# wordpress was updated to 3.8.1 version and now iam unable to edit any of the posts in visual area and text area

Tags: php, wordpress

-i updated my WordPress today morning to 3.8.1 version , after the update of my WordPress i unable to update any of them and unable to view them in visual field and text field when i press edit my post.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by this? Do you get an error of any kind? We need some more information to give you any help!

Comment: no i didnot got any error ,but when i updated to 3.8.1 after that iam unable to edit posts and pages which are published before the update of my wordpress . but i got only one message as "There is an auto-save of this post that is more recent than the version below. View the auto-save" , and when i restored that auto-save version also there is no use of it. I am unable to edit my posts which are published by me before the update of my wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Does the same thing happen if you try using a different browser that you do not normally use? For example, if you use Chrome, try and see if it works in Firefox.

If one browser works but the other does not, then you are experiencing a fairly common caching issue, where your browser is caching javascript files from the old version instead of retrieving the newly updated files.

This happens especially if you have certain types of "speed optimization" plugins or similar code running on the site, because these often create settings to have longer cache intervals for common static files such as images and css and javascript files, to make browsers not have to retrieve as much data. WordPress uses cache-busting version numbers to try to reduce this problem, but these methods are not always effective.

The only solution is to clear the browser cache, but a surprising number of people have difficulties doing that. Browsers are persistent buggers. I recommend clearing the cache, restarting the browser completely (note that some browsers, like Chrome, remain running in the background.. you have to actually kill them manually from the taskbar or similar), and then clearing the cache again after restarting it. Even then, it may take a few attempts.

Alternatively, you may have not have gotten a complete upgrade and some of the files may not be installed. There is a "Reinstall" button on the Upgrade screen that will do a complete file installation over your existing installation. This will not erase any data, it simply gets the core files from WordPress.org and reinstalls them in-place. You can try this to see if it helps. As always, before performing anything like this, make sure you have an up-to-date backup of the site.

Comment: I Checked in firefox ,chrome and i ewly installed torch n safari also but iam unable to retriew the data visually to check them and edit them .

Comment: i killed all the processes running background and cleared all the cache and re installed  my WordPress by clicking on re-install option but no use of it ! any further options?/